# kotlinx.serialization Decode object from map value taking ID from the map key

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

Using `koltinx.serialization`, is there a way to enable the "value" serializer to take it's ID from the "key" of the map entry?

For example, given the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "key1": { "name": "value1" },
    "key2": { "name": "value2" },
  }
}
```

And the serializable data class:

```
@Serializable
data class DataEntry(val id: String, val name: String)
```

How can I write a `KSerializer` for the map (or for the map "value") that will enable the `DataEntry` serializer to take the value of it's `id` field from the map "key"?

The result being a `List` (or `Map`) of:

```
DataEntry("key1", "value1"),
DataEntry("key2", "value2"),
```

I know that I can deserialise the map using `DataEntry(val name: String)` (without `id`) and then build a list of entries with `id`'s from that. But in my case, for the map "value" I actually have *many* large data types, and this would require duplicating a lot of code. I want a generic way to handle this scenario given any data type.

Comment: I would suggest writing another data class that truly represent the json format, then write converter methods between the two, rather than trying to perform complicated magic.

Comment: Yeah that is what I'm doing for now, but this question is "how to do the magic", because I as mentioned I have many large data types and want to avoid duplicating all the data classes.

Comment: What about this: 1. Create a `interface HasJsonKey { val key: String }`, 2. Implement the interfaces in your DTOs, 3. Create a util function that will convert a list of `HasJsonKey`s to a suitable `Map<String, DTO>`. The downside is that key would be duplicated in the body.